# Would scp *.git to migrate one server to another frowned upon?

Tags: linux, git

I need to migrate a Linux server that I’m going to be sunsetting shortly.  I’m not a git user but on server1 I have in say `/opt/repos/git` a couple dozen projects app fooX.git.  If I scp overnight when nobody’s using it and endusers get the new IP, make a new git user on the remote server, `chown -R git:git /opt/repos/git` it would be a smooth migration?  Or am I missing something?  Will this get all revisions and comments and history?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

It *can be* smooth migration, because you'll transfer all data in repositories, but **not** access-level settings: Git-repos can be accessed by using http(s) or ssh and both protocols *require* special and different configuration.

`chown -R git:git /opt/repos/git` will have useful effect only in case of access-type of "shared ssh-user", which isn't common case